# Handling varying JSON schema when creating a dataframe in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I've Databricks notebook that reads the delta data in JSON format every hour. So lets says at 11AM the schema of the file is as follows,

```
root
 |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- assignment: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

The next hour at 12PM the schema changes to,

```
root
 |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- company: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- assignment: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Some of the columns change from string to struct and vice-versa. So if I select the col(company.link) and the incoming schema is of type string the code fails.
How do I handle schema changes in PySpark when reading the file as my end goal is to flatten the JSON to a CSV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_dtype(df,colname):
  return [dtype for name, dtype in df.dtypes if name == colname][0]

#df has the exploded JSON data
df2 = df.select("result.number",
                "result.company",             
                "result.assignment_group")
df23 = df2

for name, cols in df2.dtypes:
  if 'struct' in get_dtype(df2, name):
    try:
      df23 = df23.withColumn(name+"_link", col(name+".link")).withColumn(name+"_value", col(name+".value")).drop(name)
    except:
      print("error")

df23.printSchema()
root
 |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- assignment_group_link: string (nullable = true)
 |-- assignment_group_value: string (nullable = true)
```

So this is what I did,

1. Created a function that identifies if the column is of type struct
2. read all the columns from the base dataframe that has the exploded result from JSON
3. then loop through the column and if it of type struct then add new columns with the nested values.